# How to number and cross-reference \subsubsection-level headers

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I'm trying to cross-reference 2 subsubsections from my document.

My structure is like:

```
\chapter{something}
\section{1.1}
\subsection{1.1.2}
\subsubsection{Number 1} \label{sssec:num1}
\subsubsection{Number 2} \label{sssec:num2}
```

I'm trying to reference both the subsubsections from my section 1.1 above. But when I use `\ref{sssec:num1}` and `\ref{sssec:num2}`, the reference is always pointing to the `\subsection{1.1.2}` for some reason.

My ToC depth is 2, so it's only showing as far as the subsection. Does anyone know a fix to this?

Thanks

Comment: You have to number the subsubsection to refer. For this put `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` in the preamble. This gives http://i.stack.imgur.com/e3PXr.png

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your comment that the `tocdepth` counter's value is equal to `2` suggests that the value of the counter `secnumdepth` is also set to `2`; if true, it would certainly explain why you can't seem to cross-reference subsubsections correctly.

The following example uses `\setcounter` to set the value of `secnumdepth` to `3`. If `secnumdepth` were left at `2` (the default value for the `report` document class), the `subsubsection` counter doesn't get incremented, and in consequence both `\label`s will end up pointing to the most recently incremented counter, which happens to be `subsection`. That's the problem behavior you're experiencing, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % default value for 'report' class is "2"
\begin{document}
\chapter{Something}

Here are cross-references to subsubsections \ref{sssec:num1} and \ref{sssec:num2}.

\section{A section header}
\subsection{A subsection header}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection} \label{sssec:num1}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection} \label{sssec:num2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! That fixed it, it looks a bit messy with all the numbers but at least it works. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: why does `secnumdepth` default to 2 for report class and what values do other classes use ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga - You should pose this comment as a *new question*. (Incidentally, I didn't design the `report` document class, and I have no personal knowledge of why or how any of the many design choices were made.)

Comment: @Mico thank you for getting back! I was curious how you got to know that as I didn't see it mentioned anywhere nor could I find it when Googling for it. So I wanted to know if there are other such good to know tips of latex. Thank you!

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga - If you search the files `report.cls` and `book.cls`, you'll find `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`. For `article.cls`, the settings are `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`. `0` is the chapter level, `1` is the section level, `2` is the subsection level, and `3` is the subsubsection level.